# Using a Jenkins pipeline multiline /multi-line string parameter

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I'm converting a bunch of jobs to use the Jenkins pipeline language.

In plain/normal Jenkins we can use parameter types including:

- string
- boolean
- choice, and also
- **multi-line string**.

A parameter using one of these types will pop up and prompt the user for input when they run the Jenkins job.

The available parameter types for Jenkins pipeline are: (According to [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines)).

- booleanParam
- choice
- file
- text
- password
- run
- string

There is no multiline string input parameter listed for pipeline. The Jenkins documentation say the documentation is "young" and still incomplete.

Has anyone managed to get a multi-line string input parameter working with the Jenkins pipeline?

Multi-line string parameters are in the out-of-the-box Jenkins package, but doesn't seem to be there in the pipeline.

Answer (score 24):

I discovered the solution by looking at the Jenkins source code:

```
parameters{ text(name: 'mytextparam', 
                 defaultValue: 'Default lines for the parameter', 
                 description: 'A description of this param')    
}
```

This pops up a multi-line text input prompt which becomes the parameter value which you can refer to later as **params.mytextparam**

This is not documented in the Jenkins Pipeline documentation, so there might be issues like it being unsupported or withdrawn in a future release.  Or it could go the other way and they might document it in the next release.

Answer (score 6):

There is a plugin that called:

"pipeline-syntax"

You should use it if you need some stuff for Jenkins pipeline.

1.Install the plugin: I installed it from "plugins" in my Jenkins server under "Manage Jenkins" then, Plugin Manager. source:https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin

2.You will see the plugin in the main screen of Jenkins on the left side. select it.

3.On the plugin select whatever you want for the plugin. here is an example of what you need now, check this out:

4. Go To Pipeline syntax dialog (/pipeline-syntax)
5. Select `properties: Set Job Properties`

[image]
6.After that press on "GENERATE PIPELINE SCRIPT".

7.copy the code (or part of it that you need) and add it to your Jenkins pipeline..

Let me know if this was helpful

Comment: At present this is under `properties: Set Job Properties` in pipeline syntax

Answer (score 2):

Multi-line string parameters are text parameters in pipeline syntax. They are described on the [Jenkins Pipeline Syntax page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters).

Example:

```
parameters { text(name: 'DEPLOY_TEXT', defaultValue: 'One\nTwo\nThree\n', description: '') }
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone whose using [JobDSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) - The Multiline option in a generated pipleline has similar arguments, but it's called [textParam](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.parameters-textParam):

```
textParam('ParameterName', 'Default value', 'Parameter description')
```